# Wordpress ajax duplicate only on page with post from category

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, loops

I have problem with ajax i WP. This code is working only when I want to show all posts but not working when I try show post from category only.

First loop show correct results but after click on load more I have posts from different category

My **function.php**

```
function miloszmich_my_load_more_scripts() {

    wp_enqueue_script('jquery');

    // register our main script but do not enqueue it yet
    wp_register_script( 'my_loadmore', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/myloadmore.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_localize_script( 'my_loadmore', 'miloszmich_loadmore_params', array(
        'ajaxurl' => site_url() . '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php', // WordPress AJAX
        'posts' => json_encode( $business_query->query_vars ), // everything about your loop is here
        'current_page' => get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1,
        'max_page' => 99
    ) );

    wp_enqueue_script( 'my_loadmore' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'miloszmich_my_load_more_scripts' );

function miloszmich_loadmore_ajax_handler(){

    // prepare our arguments for the query
    $args = json_decode( stripslashes( $_POST['query'] ), true );
    $args['paged'] = $_POST['page'] + 1; 
    $args['post_status'] = 'publish';

    // it is always better to use WP_Query but not here
    query_posts( $args );

    if( have_posts() ) :

        // run the loop
        while( have_posts() ): the_post();

      get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

        endwhile;

    endif;
    die; 
}
add_action('wp_ajax_loadmore', 'miloszmich_loadmore_ajax_handler');
add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_loadmore', 'miloszmich_loadmore_ajax_handler');
```

My **loadmore.js**

```
jQuery(function($){
    $('.miloszmich_my_load_more_scripts').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();
        var button = $(this),
            data = {
            'action': 'loadmore',
            'query': miloszmich_loadmore_params.posts, // that's how we get params from wp_localize_script() function
            'page' : miloszmich_loadmore_params.current_page
        };

        $.ajax({
            url : miloszmich_loadmore_params.ajaxurl, // AJAX handler
            data : data,
            type : 'POST',
            beforeSend : function ( xhr ) {
                button.text('Ładowanie...'); // change the button text, you can also add a preloader image
            },
            success : function( data ){
                if( data ) {
                    button.text( 'Pokaż jeszcze więcej' ).prev().before(data); // insert new posts
                    miloszmich_loadmore_params.current_page++;

                    if ( miloszmich_loadmore_params.current_page == miloszmich_loadmore_params.max_page )
                        button.remove(); // if last page, remove the button

                    // you can also fire the "post-load" event here if you use a plugin that requires it
                    // $( document.body ).trigger( 'post-load' );
                } else {
                    button.remove(); // if no data, remove the button as well
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

My **loop on custom page**

```
//define the inner query
            $query_vars = [
                    'post_type' => 'post',
                    'posts_per_page' => 4,
                    'offset' => 1,
                    'cat' => 3,
                    'orderby'   => array(
                        'date' =>'DESC',
                        'menu_order'=>'ASC',
                    )

            ];
            // execute the inner query
            $business_query = new WP_Query($query_vars);
            while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

                /*
                 * Include the Post-Format-specific template for the content.
                 * If you want to override this in a child theme, then include a file
                 * called content-___.php (where ___ is the Post Format name) and that will be used instead.
                 */
                get_template_part( 'template-parts/content', get_post_format() );

            // End the loop.
            endwhile;

            // if (  $wp_query->max_num_pages > 1 )
            echo '<div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"></div></row>'; // prevent for bad order
            echo '<div class="btn miloszmich_my_load_more_scripts">Pokaż więcej wpisów</div>'; // load more fn


            wp_reset_postdata();
```

Steps on custom pages with all categories loop: 
I have 4 correctly posts, after click on more posts AJAX gives me correct 4 next.

Steps on custom pages with 1 categorie loop: 
I have 4 correctly posts, after click on more posts AJAX gives me 4 next from different category (random).

Answer (score 0):

If i understand correct, you want to limit your query to a specific category.
If thats the case then you need to include category__not_in => array(YOUR_CAT_ID) in your query vars